# venv vs virtualenv - Why does venv not use the current pip and setuptools?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, python-venv

When using `python -m venv env` to create a new virtual environment in python3.X, `env` does not contain the `pip` and `setuptools` versions I would expect. Instead, it contains quite "old" versions: `pip (8.1.1)` and `setuptools (20.7.0)` as of June 2018.

On the other hand, when using `virtualenv env` (installed via `pip install virtualenv`), the pip and setuptools packages are the latest available, i.e. `pip (10.0.1)` and `setuptools (39.2.0)` as of June 2018.

The way I understood it, `venv` is the **preferred module to build virtual environments** because it does not need to create a new instance of the Python interpreter and uses the present modules (symlinks in Linux, copies in Windows) without needing to install anything ( https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4hsudz/pyvenv_vs_virtualenv/d2s2cda ).

**How come that `venv`'s `pip` version doesn't match the current system's one? And that the behaviour using `virtualenv` is so different?**

PS:

A short term **solution** is to use `pip install --upgrade pip` in the `env`. But that doesn't seem right to me. Minimum viable **solution**:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/lionel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
$ python -m venv env
$ . env/bin/activate
(env) $ # Here I am at version 8.1.1 of pip. Why did venv create its own pip,
(env) $ # instead of linking to the system one? As seen before, that was 10.0.1.
(env) $ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.1
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1
(env) $ pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
pip           10.0.1 
pkg-resources 0.0.0  
setuptools    20.7.0 
(env) $ # Solved, now pip is the one I was expecting!
```

Comment: Your "python" version is 3.6 but your pip version is hooked into 3.5.  Looks like you've screwed up your environment somehow.  For 3.6, the vendored pip and setuptools is usually 9.0.1 / 28.8.0 respectively (but this can change depending on who compiled Python).

Comment: Psst! Stop using venv, use pipenv. Thank me later.

Comment: Hello wim and Ramazan! Thank for the answers! @wim : indeed, pip is hooked to 3.5. I understand that the solution to my problem lies in the fact that I have python3.5 and python3.6 installed on my Ubuntu.

Trouble arose because pip asked to be updated (`You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.0 is available.`) when I used `venv`, which it didn't ask for when using `virtualenv`, as pip then already was the newest version.

Thanks wim for showing what the problem was.

Comment: Solved by uninstalling pip:
** `python -m pip uninstall pip` **
I will try to ignore the warning `You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.` in the future.

Comment: The problem remains the same when the pip is hooked to the python in the right way (see edit in my question): 1. BEFORE venv, I have `pip (10.0.1)` for python 3.6   AFTER venv, I have `pip (8.1.1)` for python 3.6/

Answer (score 4):

Not trying to revive an old thread, but here is the answer i found to why this happens when using venv- short answer-

> venv calls ensurepip.version() to get the version- that gets the bundled pip version.

Credits to original answer from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689514/why-python3-m-venv-myenv-installs-older-version-of-pip-into-myenv-than-any-ve)